# Is there any way to edit iCal event to the iPhone Calendar from the custom App?

Tags: ios, events, calendar, icalendar

Is there any way to edit iCal event to the iPhone Calendar from the custom App?
In my app i have to save event to device cal. and how to edit that saved event in device cal from my app.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use

```
- (EKEvent *)eventWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
```

--> you will get the EKEvent with the particular identifier you send...

--> then do the changing in its details like "description", "Date" etc

--> add this event to the EKEventStore and add it to iCal using

```
[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

i guess it should work this is totally based on my memory.

Comment: this is for saving event to iphone cal but i need how to update the same event in iphone calendar

Comment: you  only need "[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];"  to save the event.This "- (EKEvent *)eventWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;" will fetch you the already added event to your calendar you just have to modify and re-save .